# Changing the value of string on SCNText produces no change

Tags: ios, scenekit, scnnode, scntext

I am reading the gyro and changing the string of a `SCNText` geometry to the gyro's yaw value. The change occurs inside the gyro handler that is called every 1/30 seconds. The `SCNText` geometry was created with Interface Builder.

I am using this code to retrieve a reference to the text:

```
SCNNode *textNode = [scene.rootNode childNodeWithName:@"yawText" recursively:YES];
self.text = [textNode geometry]; 
//self.txt is declared as @property (strong, nonatomic) SCNText *text;
```

Later on the gyro handle I do this:

```
CGFloat yaw = convertToDegrees(attitude.yaw);
[weakSelfText setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", yaw]];
NSLog(@"yaw = %1f", yaw);

// I had to declare weakSelfText outside the gyro handler
// because Xcode was complaining
// weakSelfText is declared like this
// __weak typeof(self.text) weakSelfText = self.text;
```

`NSLog` prints the values correctly but there is no change on the `SCNText`.

Yes, I have tried to change the text on the main thread. No change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `string` on your SCNText geometry is sufficient.

```
textNode.geometry.string = "0.5"
```

If you see no change, then weakSelfText doesn't point to where you think it does. Make sure you're not dropping a reference somewhere:

```
NSAssert(weakSelfText == textNode.geometry, @"pointers not the same")
```

Comment: brilliant! THANKS!